# Django login - do not go register new user

Tags: django

I am using the django default views and url settings for login, logout, password reset and so on - mostly works. However when the user enters invalid login credentials I get a backtrace which starts like this:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/

registration/login.html
...
```

My interpretation of this is that the login view wants to redirect me to a user registration page, but I would rather return back to my login page and display an error message. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you changed the login url, did you specify it in the setting like this:

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
```

Comment: I don't really understand this; I wanted to have `/` as `LOGIN_URL` - have tried both setting `LOGIN_URL= "/"` and `LOGIN_URL = "/accounts/login/` - and they both(?) work. The point is what happens when login fails - I then do not want to go to a new registration page - which is seems django wants to send me to.

Comment: look at this maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11678703/django-redirect-after-login-error

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129091/how-to-redirect-to-same-page-on-failed-login